# Forcing Chrome browser to use a specific network interface?

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, google-chrome, proxy

How can I force Chrome to use a specific network interface (e.g., tun1)?

Some programs such as `curl` has an option for choosing a specific network interface.

In Windows, [ForceBindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip) allows you to force an application to use a specific network interface / IP address.

I wonder if there is a solution in Ubuntu/Linux to do so.

Alternatively, since we can set a proxy in Chrome; can we redirect a local IP to a network interface or vice versa?

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Comment: @David I added the version, but I doubt it can affect the answer, as an answer probably works for all Linux-based systems.

Comment: I have a workaround not a solution. I can run a VM and tie the VM to a specific network interface. then run chrome inside the VM :)

Comment: this is still a good and relevant question

Answer (score 5):

This is the perfect use case for network namespaces, which have been part of Linux since 2016 or earlier. Here's an example with comments to get you started:

```
# enable forwarding
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# create the network namespace
ip netns add chrome

# create the virtual nic and it's peer
ip link add chrome type veth peer name chrome-peer

# assign the peer to the network namespace
ip link set chrome-peer netns chrome

# assign an ip address
ip addr add 192.0.2.1/24 dev chrome

# bring up interface
ip link set chrome up

# similar network setup for network namespace
ip netns exec chrome ip link set lo up
ip netns exec chrome ip addr add 192.0.2.2/24 dev chrome-peer
ip netns exec chrome ip route add default via 192.0.2.1
ip netns exec chrome ip link set chrome-peer up

# allow forwarding and add enable NAT
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.0.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.0.2.0/24 -o tun1 -j MASQUERADE

# pop a shell in the namespace
ip netns exec chrome bash

# check that you're in the namespace
ip netns identify

# run the browser as your local user
runuser -u Barry google-chrome
```

Answer (score 1):

## Background

Linux has `SO_BINDTODEVICE` option to bind a socket to a specific network interface.

## Idea

Chromium uses the libc functions to invoke a syscall, including the `connect()` syscall that's used to perform a network request. We can patch the `connect()` function to call `setsockopt(SO_BINDTODEVICE)` before performing the `connect()` syscall. This can be done by preloading a shared library via `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable.

## Minimal working example:

### connect.c

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define IFACE_NAME "tun0"
#define IPV6_TO_BIND "fddd:bbbb::2"

static void set_bind_addr6(int fd)
{
        struct sockaddr_in6 addr;

        memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
        addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        inet_pton(AF_INET6, IPV6_TO_BIND, &addr.sin6_addr);
        bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
}

int connect(int fd, const struct sockaddr *daddr, socklen_t addrlen)
{
        int family = daddr->sa_family;

        if (family == AF_INET || family == AF_INET6) {

                if (family == AF_INET6)
                        set_bind_addr6(fd);

                setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, IFACE_NAME, sizeof(IFACE_NAME));
        }

        return syscall(__NR_connect, fd, daddr, addrlen);
}
```

Adjust `IFACE_NAME` and `IPV6_TO_BIND` with your machine setup. If you don't wish to use IPv6, you can omit the IPv6 binding code.

If you wish to use IPv6, the IPv6 binding is required because the caller sets the wrong bind address. It also helps you to choose which IPv6 address you're going to use for outgoing connections.

The binding is not required for IPv4.

## Usage

```
ammarfaizi2@integral2:/tmp$ gcc -fpic -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -shared -O3 connect.c -o connect.so
ammarfaizi2@integral2:/tmp$ export LD_PRELOAD="/tmp/connect.so"
ammarfaizi2@integral2:/tmp$ /opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

#### Tested and worked fine on Ubuntu 22.04 with IPv4 and IPv6 network

## Update

### 30 June 2023:

- Add IPv6 support.
- Remove inline Assembly (make it portable to other architectures).